# not POSTing variables from form to $self

Tags: php, forms, post, pdo

**EDIT**:
added new code block

```
//SCRIPT TO INSERT THE CHANGED ENTRY
    echo "the <b>CONFIRM CHANGES</b> button was pressed<br /><br />";
    $STH = $DBH->("INSERT INTO register (register, location, type, capacity, length, qty, serial, cert, lastinsp, inspby, status, datein, dateout, notes) value (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");

    //bind the parameters to the variables
    $data = array("$register", "$location", "$type", "$capacity", "$qty", "$serial", "$cert", "$lastinsp", "$inspby", "$status", "$datein", "$dateout", "$notes");
    $STH->execute($data);
    echo "Data has been written to the database!<br /><br />";
    echo "<hr />";
```

I've given in to peer pressure and started re-writing my project using PDO (thankyou by the way, it seems easier to get my head around!)

I'm passing the row `$id` from a form via `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']` but am not getting the variable for the next db query.

I hope that makes sense, affected lines are commented, code is below.

thanks in advance.

```
<?php
//Global Settings
$pagetitle="PDO Test";
$menu="no";
require 'header.php';
require 'dbvars.php';
require 'dafunc.php';

//Page Specific Settigns
$self=htmlentities($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);

//connect to the database
try {
    $dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=$sqlhost;dbname=$sqldb", $sqluser, $sqlpass);
    /*** echo a message saying we have connected ***/
    echo "Connected to <b>$sqlhost</b> : <b>$sqldb</b><br /><br />";
    $dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    }
catch(PDOException $e)
    {
    echo $e->getMessage();
    }

//if the EDIT button was pressed, do this
if(isset($_POST['edit']))
{   
    $id=$_POST['id'];

    //SCRIPT TO EDIT ENTRY
    echo "the <b>EDIT</b> button was pressed<br /><br />";
    echo "The ID is: $id<br /><br />";

    //this is where I'm trying to use the $id passed from the last form on this page
    $sth = $dbh -> prepare( "select * from register WHERE id=\"$id\"" );

    $sth -> execute();
    $row = $sth -> fetch();

    echo "<form action=\"$self\" method=\"post\">";
    echo "<table width=\"372\" border=\"0\" align=\"center\">";
          echo "<tr><td>ID</td><td>" . $row['id'] . "</td></tr>";
          echo "<input name=\"id\" type=\"hidden\" value=\"" . $row['id'] ."\" />";
          echo "<tr><td>Register</td><td><input name=\"register\" type=\"text\" value=\"". $row['register'] ."\"/></td></tr>";
          echo "<tr><td>Location</td><td><input name=\"location\" type=\"text\" value=\"". $row['location'] ."\"/></td></tr>";
          echo "<tr><td>Type</td><td><input name=\"type\" type=\"text\" value=\"". $row['type'] ."\"/></td></tr>";
          echo "<tr><td>Capacity</td><td><input name=\"capacity\" type=\"text\" value=\"". $row['capacity'] ."\"/></td></tr>";
          echo "<tr><td>Length</td><td><input name=\"length\" type=\"text\" value=\"". $row['length'] ."\"/></td></tr>";
          echo "<tr><td>Qty</td><td><input name=\"qty\" type=\"text\" value=\"". $row['qty'] ."\"/></td></tr>";
          echo "<tr><td>Serial#</td><td><input name=\"serial\" type=\"text\" value=\"". $row['serial'] ."\"/></td></tr>";
          echo "<tr><td>Certificate#</td><td><input name=\"cert\" type=\"text\" value=\"". $row['cert'] ."\"/></td></tr>";
          echo "<tr><td>Last Inspection Completed On</td><td><input name=\"lastinsp\" type=\"text\" value=\"". $row['lastinsp'] ."\"/></td></tr>";
          echo "<tr><td>Last Inspection Completed By</td><td><input name=\"inspby\" type=\"text\" value=\"". $row['inspby'] ."\"/></td></tr>";
          echo "<tr><td>Date introduced into service</td><td><input name=\"datein\" type=\"text\" value=\"". $row['datein'] ."\"/></td></tr>";
          echo "<tr><td>Date removed from service</td><td><input name=\"dateout\" type=\"text\" value=\"". $row['dateout'] ."\"/></td></tr>";
          echo "<tr><td>Notes</td><td><input name=\"notes\" type=\"text\" value=\"". $row['notes'] ."\"/></td></tr>";
    echo "</table>";
    echo "<input type=\"submit\" name=\"confirm_change\" id=\"confirm_change\" value=\"Confirm Changes\" />";
    echo "</form>";
}

//if the confirm_change button was pressed, do this
if(isset($_POST['confirm_change']))
{   
    //fetch form values
    $id = $_POST['id'];
    $register = $_POST['register'];
    $location = $_POST['location'];
    $type = $_POST['type'];
    $capacity = $_POST['capacity'];
    $length = $_POST['length'];
    $qty = $_POST['qty'];
    $serial = $_POST['serial'];
    $cert = $_POST['cert'];
    $lastinsp = $_POST['lastinsp'];
    $inspby = $_POST['inspby'];
    $datein = $_POST['datein'];
    $dateout = $_POST['dateout'];
    $status = $_POST['status'];
    $notes = $_POST['notes'];

    //SCRIPT TO DELETE ENTRY
    echo "the <b>CONFIRM CHANGES</b> button was pressed<br /><br />";
    /*
    $STH = $DBH->("INSERT INTO folks (register, location, type, capacity, length, qty, serial, cert, lastinsp, inspby, status, datein, dateout, notes) value (:register, :location, :type, :capacity, :length, :qty, :serial, :cert, :lastinsp, :inspby, :status, :datein, :dateout, :notes)");

    //bind the parameters to the variables
    $data = array("$register", "$location", "$type", "$capacity", "$qty", "$serial", "$cert", "$lastinsp", "$inspby", "$status", "$datein", "$dateout", "$notes");
    $STH->execute($data);
    echo "Data has been written to the database!<br /><br />";
    */
}

//if the DELETE button was pressed, do this
if(isset($_POST['delete']))
{   
    //SCRIPT TO DELETE ENTRY
    echo "the <b>DELETE</b> button was pressed<br /><br />";
}

//if the edit button wasn't pressed, do this instead
echo "  <form method=\"post\" action=\"$self\">
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <th>ID</th>
                    <th>REGISTER</th>
                    <th>LOCATION</th>
                    <th>TYPE</th>
                    <th>CAPACITY</th>
                    <th>LENGTH</th>
                    <th>QTY</th>
                    <th>SERIAL#</th>
                    <th>CERT#</th>
                    <th>LAST INSPECTION</th>
                    <th>BY</th>
                    <th>DATE IN</th>
                    <th>DATE OUT</th>
                    <th>NOTES</th>
                </tr>";


//get data from the db
$sql = "SELECT * FROM register";
    foreach ($dbh->query($sql) as $row)
        {
          echo "<tr>";
          echo "<td>" . $row['id'] . "</td>";
          echo "<td>" . $row['register'] . "</td>";
          echo "<td>" . $row['location'] . "</td>";
          echo "<td>" . $row['type'] . "</td>";
          echo "<td>" . $row['capacity'] . "</td>";
          echo "<td>" . $row['length'] . "</td>";
          echo "<td>" . $row['qty'] . "</td>";
          echo "<td>" . $row['serial'] . "</td>";
          echo "<td>" . $row['cert'] . "</td>";
          echo "<td>" . $row['lastinsp'] . "</td>";
          echo "<td>" . $row['inspby'] . "</td>";
          echo "<td>" . $row['datein'] . "</td>";
          echo "<td>" . $row['dateout'] . "</td>";
          echo "<td>" . $row['notes'] . "</td>";
          //this is where I'm getting the $id from for the edit script
          echo "<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"id\" id=\"" . $row['id'] . "\">";
          echo "<td><input type=\"submit\" name=\"edit\" id=\"edit\" value=\"Edit\" /></td>";
          echo "<td><input type=\"submit\" name=\"delete\" id=\"delete\" value=\"Delete\" /></td>";
          echo "</tr>";
        }
echo "</table></form>";


?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're just using `execute` incorrectly. First, you should have:

```
$sth = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO folks (register, location, type, capacity, length, qty, serial, cert, lastinsp, inspby, status, datein, dateout, notes) value (:register, :location, :type, :capacity, :length, :qty, :serial, :cert, :lastinsp, :inspby, :status, :datein, :dateout, :notes)");
```

Then, as your using the named parameters like ":register", you need to supply an associative array in execute like:

```
bind the parameters to the variables
$data = array(
    ":register" => $register,
    ":location" => $location,
    //...
    ":notes" => $notes);
$sth->execute($data);
```

If you just want to pass an array of the argument values you can just put ? marks in the SQL string passed to `prepare` (see below).

---

Your first query (in the edit `if` block) needs fixing too. You should never put POST data directly into your SQL queries because doing so leaves you vulnerable to [SQL injection attacks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection). You first need to "escape" any control characters (e.g. quotes) in the POST data. The `prepare` method can be used to do this like so:

```
$sth = $dbh->prepare("select * from register WHERE id=?");
$sth->execute(array($id));
```

When execute is called here, the array of values supplied are used to "fill in" the question marks in the prepared statement `$sth`, and then that statement is executed. Have a look at the examples on the [PDO::prepare](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php) documentation page.

Comment: can you see why `$id=$_POST['id'];` isn't being passed from the form to the EDIT script?  Thats the part thats tripping me up at the moment.  the edit form displays, but `$id` isn't and the form isn't pre-filling with the row from the db.

Comment: I don't know, if `$_POST['id']` isn't there it isn't there and you need to see why not. To be sure, try just doing `var_dump($_POST)` after the `if(isset($_POST['edit'])) {` line.

Comment: result of `var_dump($_POST)` is `array(2) { ["id"]=> string(0) "" ["edit"]=> string(4) "Edit" } ` thanks for the help.

Comment: Ah okay, so `$_POST['id']` just isn't getting set properly. I see the problem! Look at about the fifth line from the bottom of your code: `echo "<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"id\" id=\"" . $row['id'] . "\">";` Here you're making the hidden input have `id` equal to `$row['id']`, but what you want to do is make its `value` equal to `$row['id']`. The HTML `id` attribute has its own separate meaning. Change that and try it again.

Comment: So to clarify, that line should be: `echo "<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"id\" value=\"" . $row['id'] . "\">";`

Comment: wow, thanks for that!  just to clarify, could you cast an eye over the extra code block in the OP and let me know if i'm on the right track?

Comment: No problem. I'm not familiar with PDO, but looks like you've got the basic structure right. You definitely need to make sure you're doing the statement preparing stuff that I mentioned in my original answer correctly, so I'd recommend checking all your queries again. Just to make the code clearer and more efficient, you could link up all of your `if` blocks, because you only want one of them to happen each time right: So `if(edit) {} else if (delete) {} else ...` etc.